# Magento Paypal Ask to create Account even though account is set not to (sandbox)

Tags: php, api, magento, paypal

I am using Paypal Standard for Magento and I have 2 stores. On my US store, I can checkout fine without creating a account. My store is USD based currency so that is what is passed to paypal. On Europe, the portal ask me to either create a account, or sign up with an existing. It does not allow me to make a purchase anonymously.

When I go to Paypal Profile > Payment Preferences, I can clearly see that Paypal Account Optional is turned on. But it appears it only applies the US users only. Is this true ?

So what could be the issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely within Magento. There is a setting in:
System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout
entitled "Allow Guest Checkout". Make sure this is selected to Yes.

Comment: I think its pretty confusing to have 2 settings that do the samething. Anyhow I think maybe referring to the Downloadable Products setting with the samething. It doesnt apply. I got into the code and got down to the core parameters being passed. Turns out that just changing the state and country is what makes the biggest difference. So there is something on paypal that is looking at those parameters and forcing it to do what its doing